# How to reduce this 5 preg_replaces lines in 1 line?

Tags: php, optimization, preg-replace

I belive minimal is better, so I'm wondering how could I reduce/optimize these 5 lines in 1 line?

```
#JPG
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)\.jpg" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<img src="$1.jpg">', $post[message]);

#JPEG
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)\.jpeg" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<img src="$1.jpeg">', $post[message]);

#GIF
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)\.gif" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<img src="$1.gif">', $post[message]);

#PNG
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)\.png" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<img src="$1.png">', $post[message]);

#BMP
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)\.bmp" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<img src="$1.bmp">', $post[message]);
```

Comment: what do you want to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an alternation:

```php
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp))" target="_blank">.+?<\/a>/',
                              '<img src="$1">', $post[message]);
```

Note that I have removed the second capture group, which was the anchor text, as your regex replacement was not even using it.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for your help and note. Your code works correctly and it's exactly what I was lookin for :)